# Get Text from MVC dropdown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC dropdown List that i am populating from the server. Like so

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlContent", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "<Select Message>", new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: messageTitle" })
```

I have made the value of the list observable

```
self.messageTitle = ko.observable();
```

I am only receiving an int value this way and what i need is the selected text in the dropdown.

I also have another list where i am attempting the same thing and it looks like so.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EblastSubject, new SelectList(Model.ListEblastSubject, "SubjectID", "Subject"), "<Select Subject>", new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: eblastSubject" })
```

again i am getting the Id  with

```
self.eblastSubject = ko.observable();
```

but not the selected text

Comment: You're not showing enough code for us to reproduce the issue. Please include a [mcve], or at the very least more context on (a) client side code, (b) what the input / data for that code looks like,

Comment: Have you tried porting all of your code to angular??

Answer (score 2):

The observable should pick up the text. Try this:

Controller

```
var items = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };
ViewBag.MyList = new SelectList(items);
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList", null, "-- Select Message --", new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: messageTitle" })
```

Comment: Thanks but no dice the value i am getting is the Id of the item selected and i need the selected text.

Comment: The trick is for the `<option>`s not to have a `value` attribute. Do that and KO will pick up the text, just like in the sample above

Comment: so on the other list what is coming in is subjectID and then subject i need the value of subject so something like value: i[1].messagetitle

Comment: If you want the _selected text_, like I said the easiest way is to aim for these to be rendered: <option>just text</option>